# SML code and not compiling, asking for andalso

Tags: compiler-errors, sml

In my SML code this line is not running

`if check(e1) == Num and check(e2) == Num then Num else raise TypeError "ill-typed"`

I get a compile error `Error: syntax error: replacing  AND with  ANDALSO`

Does anyone know why this is not compiling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`and` is a very different keyword in SML from what you think. `and` is used for defining mutually recursive functions, while `andalso` is the keyword used for boolean and.

Also, note that `==` is not equality checking in SML. `=` is.